# IndexView is missing a QuerySet. Define IndexView.model - tutorial 4 django

Tags: python, django

I'm following [this tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial04/). At the end of the page I had to modify my views.py and my urls.py

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
               url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
               url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',
                   views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
               url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/results/$',
                   views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
               url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$',
               views.vote, name='vote'),
              ]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render 
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.views import generic
from .models import Choice, Question

class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

# SebasSBM's note: following the answer below, I assume that this method
#                  was wrongly identated like this, in the original case
def get_queryset(self):
    """Return the last five published questions."""
    return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]

class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'

class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'
```

When I try to access to the admin site or the poll app I got this:

> ImproperlyConfigured at /polls/

```
IndexView is missing a QuerySet. Define IndexView.model, IndexView.queryset, or
override IndexView.get_queryset().

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
Django Version:     1.8.3
Exception Type:     ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:    

IndexView is missing a QuerySet. Define IndexView.model, IndexView.queryset, or
override IndexView.get_queryset().

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
Django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg/django/views/generic/list.py in get_queryset, line 44

Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

['/home/eddy/Documentos/django/mysite',
 '/home/eddy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-18.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-18.0.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv-13.1.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/eddy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
```

Comment: it may be a silly thing, but is your indentation correct? The imports and the following lines in `views.py`

Comment: Have you gone through the first three tutorials , if so i don't think you should get this error

Comment: of course the DB is setup and populated, right?

Comment: in `admin.py` have you registered the model? `admin.site.register(models.Question)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`IndexView` should be

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published questions."""
        return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

Indentation matters. My guess is that your `IndexView` is

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

def get_queryset(self):
    """Return the last five published questions."""
    return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

Comment: Yes! thank you! I've to tabulate 2 times! and fixed it.

Comment: I used to use tabs for identations too, but eventually I realized that it is better using 4 spaces instead. With time, you will notice it is better using 4 spaces (even if it is less comfortable at beginning). PEP-0008 recommends it this way. Also, it is annoying to see how tabstop=8 in other editors by default and having to edit it, or in GitHub, for example.

Comment: Just take it as an advice, not a lecture :-). See https://www.jwz.org/doc/tabs-vs-spaces.html for more information.

Answer (score -1):

//you must use same context_object_name in index.html {{latest.question.list}}